# Does installing FTP 7.5 on Winows 2008 require a reboot?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I want to install the new FTP 7.5 on a Windows 2008 server. Do I need to schedule this for a time when it is ok to Reboot the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't installed the FTP 7.0 Feature within the Webserver role, then No, it will not require a reboot.

If you have installed the FTP 7.0 Feature within the Webserver role, then Yes, you will require a reboot to fully remove FTP 7.0 before installing FTP 7.5.

~MBT